# Error: 'The page has expired due to inactivity' Laravel (Error in production server)

Tags: php, laravel, csrf

My problem basically is that the server where the app is in production gives me the error that the page has expired.

I have reviewed and modified some things because the form works on my local server where I developed the application.

I placed in the middleware "VerifyCsrfToken" the route to avoid the problem of the token.

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        //
        'admin/login'
    ];
}
```

**Result:** the request was sent, the Auth::attempt() was succesfully, but when I redirect to the panel the Auth::user() is null.

Comment: Are your routes using the `web` middleware group?

Comment: I think I tried using that middleware too, because I did not have it. Let me check it.

Comment: I got the same error.